# Прошу помочь с отображением "спрайта" svg

Tags: html, svg

Начал смотреть в сторону svg, создаю свой спрайт с использованием symbol, но не могу вывести символ в теге Use, помогите разобраться в чем причина.
сам svg находится в отдельном файле, подключаю таким образом:

```
<svg class="unit">
    <use xlink:href="iconsSvg.svg#gear"></use>
</svg>
```

собственно кусочек svg, который подключаю:

```
<symbol id="gear" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" 
xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M 122.6 16.8C 119.9 26 117.4 34.2 
116.9 35.1C 116.5 35.9 114.2 37.2 111.8 37.9C 109.4 38.6 104.2 40.7 100.1 
42.6L 92.8 46L 76 37C 66.8 32 58.9 28 58.4 28C 57.3 28 28 57.2 28 58.3C 28 
58.8 32 66.6 37 75.7C 44.9 90.2 45.8 92.5 44.8 94.4C 44.1 95.5 41.8 101 39.5 
106.4L 35.4 116.4L 27.4 118.8C 23.1 120.1 15.1 122.5 9.8 124.1L 9.53674e-07 
127.1L 9.53674e-07 149.3L 9.53674e-07 171.6L 16.8 176.5C 26 179.1 34 181.8 
34.6 182.4C 35.3 183 36.6 186 37.5 189C 38.5 192 40.6 197.4 42.1 200.9L 45 
207.3L 36 224C 31.1 233.2 27 241.1 27 241.6C 27 242.1 33.7 249.2 41.9 257.4C 
51.9 267.3 57.3 272.1 58.3 271.7C 59.1 271.4 66.9 267.3 75.5 262.6L 91.3 
254L 98.4 257.4C 102.3 259.3 108 261.5 111.1 262.5L 116.7 264.3L 121 278.9C 
123.4 286.9 125.7 295 126.2 296.7L 127.1 300L 149.4 300L 171.8 300L 173.8 
293.2C 175 289.5 177.3 281.5 179.1 275.4L 182.3 264.3L 187.9 262.5C 190.9 
261.6 196.7 259.3 200.7 257.5L 208 254.1L 224.4 263.1C 233.4 268 241.2 272 
241.7 272C 242.9 272 272 242.7 272 241.4C 272 240.8 268 232.9 263 223.8L 
254.1 207.3L 258.1 198C 260.3 192.9 262.4 187.4 262.7 185.8C 263 184.3 263.8 
182.6 264.4 182.3C 265 181.9 273.1 179.3 282.5 176.5L 299.5 171.3L 299.8 
149.3L 300 127.3L 281.8 121.9L 263.6 116.4L 260.5 108.4C 258.8 104.1 256.4 
98.7 255.2 96.4L 253.1 92.3L 261.2 77.4C 265.6 69.2 269.7 61.5 270.3 60.2C 
271.3 58.1 270.2 56.7 256.4 42.9C 248.2 34.7 241.1 28 240.6 28C 240.1 28 
232.1 32.1 222.9 37.1L 206.1 46.1L 201.8 43.9C 199.4 42.7 194.1 40.5 190 39L 
182.5 36.2L 177 18.1L 171.5 0L 149.5 0L 127.5 0L 122.6 16.8zM 165.8 77.6C 
207.6 86.1 234.2 128.2 223.5 168.5C 216.7 193.7 195.7 214.6 170 221.6C 160.4 
224.3 143 224.1 132.3 221.2C 111.6 215.6 92.5 198.5 83.9 178C 70.3 145.4 
81.5 109.6 112 88.3C 115.6 85.8 119.8 83.3 121.5 82.7C 123.1 82.2 125.1 81.3 
125.8 80.7C 127.8 79.1 144 76.2 151.3 76.1C 155 76 161.6 76.7 165.8 77.6z"/ 

</symbol>
```

---

Блин сам по тупости пропустил закрывающий тег , блин пол дня убил.

Comment: Бывает. Приходите ещё с новыми вопросами. :)